# CloudFlare Flexible SSL changing font

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

I have a question regarding CloudFlare's new Flexible SSL. I am on a free account there, so I figured I'd ask the community here before submitting a support ticket (since they don't appear to have a forum).

How do I properly handle a forced SSL redirect? I want all traffic to my site to use SSL, but right now it's bypassed. CloudFlare is enabled, and manually going to https:// works perfectly, but what is the "proper" way for forcing SSL? Do I need to use my domain registrar to redirect all requests to https? Not a problem if that's the case, I know how to do that, but I don't know if that's the "proper" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually use [PageRules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-) to force http:// to https://

You should also make sure you don't have any [mixed content](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170476-How-do-I-fix-the-SSL-Mixed-Content-Error-Message-) issues.

Note: We don't provide a forum because we don't want people sharing sensitive information (server IPs, etc.) in a public arena. Everything is handled via support for that reason.

Comment: Sorry for the late response; I used PageRules and fixed my mixed content issues and everything is great. (Just forgot to come back and mark this as resolved.) Thank you! And yeah, it does make sense as to why you don't have a forum, I just try not to bother the support people (especially on a free account) unless I have to. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to hear all is well!